# calculate the modularity on each step

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, complex-networks

```
library(igraph)
g=graph.famous("Zachary")
c=edge.betweenness.community(g)
a=membership(c)
c$merges
b=community.to.membership(g,c$merges,steps=33)

[1] 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 4 5 3 1 1 1 4 4 3 1 4 1 4 1 4 4 2 2 4 2 2 4 4 2 4 4

[1] 9 4 0 0 0 0 5 0 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 8
```

I expect b is same with membership(c) because there are 33 steps.  But why is b different from membership(c)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in igraph because even the following does not work:

```
> library(igraph)
> g <- graph.full(3)
> c <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
> community.to.membership(g, c$merges, steps=1)$membership
```

This gives me a membership vector of `1 2 0`, which is clearly wrong; the correct result should be `1 0 0` or `0 1 1`. Actually, you can fix the bug by subtracting 1 from the merge matrix:

```
> g <- graph.famous("zachary")
> c <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
> membership(c)
[1] 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 4 5 3 1 1 1 4 4 3 1 4 1 4 1 4 4 2 2 4 2 2 4 4 2 4 4
> community.to.membership(g, c$merges-1, steps=29)$membership
[1] 0 0 2 0 3 3 3 0 1 4 3 0 0 0 1 1 3 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

These two membership vectors are essentially the same (with a bit of reindexing). Note that you only need 29 steps to reach the same membership vector because there are 34 vertices in the graph and you have 5 communities, so you need to perform 34-5=29 merges. Performing 33 steps would get you a single community only.

I will file a bug report for this in igraph's bug tracker.

Comment: Awesome! How did you find this solution by subtracting 1 from the merge matrix? I think the process of solving this problem is very important.Thank you.

Comment: Well, I was cheating ;) I am one of the developers of igraph and I know that the R interface has recently switched from zero-based indexing (which is very natural in the C core of igraph) to one-based indexing (which is what most R users would expect), so I simply suspected that community.to.membership slipped through the net and still expected a zero-based merge matrix.